# Priority quene based on argument of person class

Tags: java, class, priority-queue

Hey I've class called person that looks like below

```
PersonClass[] person= {
            new PersonClass(90234234434L, "Name", "Surname", Age, "Street", Priority),
            ...
            ...
    };
```

Then I create array

```
 ArrayDeque<String> arrayDeque = new ArrayDeque<>();
```

edit: my mistake, I'm already using

```
PriorityQueue<String> priorityQueue = new PriorityQueue<>
```

I tried many ways but I cant solve, how to sort this person array by priority value. If something is unclear, ask. Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Which argument is used for the priority ?

Comment: priority has a intiger value between 0 and 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort your `PersonClass` objects using `Comparable`.

First you have to `implements` `Comparable` in your `PersonClass` and override the `compareTo` method like below,

```
@Override
public int compareTo(PersonClass person) {
    return this.Priority - person.Priority;
}
```

Then you can sort the person array in your method using `sort` method in `Arrays`

```
Arrays.sort(array)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a priority queue, use, well, `PriorityQueue`. Assuming on `PersonClass` the method to get the priority value is `getPriority`, you could do:

```
PriorityQueue<PersonClass> priorityQ = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.comparing(PersonClass::getPriority));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a PriorityQueue provided by Java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html

You need to provide a Comparator if the objects are not primitive types.

Then use `add()` method to fill it. Then use `poll()` to get the first element and remove it form the queue:

```
PriorityQueue pq = new PriorityQueue(new PersonComparator());
for (PersonClass person : persons) {
    pq.add(person);
}

// later
PersonClass firstInQueue = pq.poll();
```